# Javascript `confirm()` execute before anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code which is executed after an AJAX call is done.

```
req.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if (response == "  ok"){
        // values are confirmed
        this.s = this._s
        this.e = this._e
        this.assign = this._assign
        this.y = roomline.snapHeight(this.assign);
        console.log(response)
        drawscreen()

            if (confirm('Would you also like to apply a discount/credit?')){
            var link = "?some_get_request"
            self.location = "assignDiscount.php" + link;
            }

    } else  {
        alert(response)
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have a bunch of stuff that should happen before the `confirm()` dialog displays (like `drawscreen()` or `console.log`).

The problem is none of this stuff happens **before** the confirm dialog but just after! I should see "  ok" in my javascript console: rather, I see it after I press the "cancel" button on the confirm dialog. This makes no sense: "  ok" should be there while I see the pop up dialog. Why is this and how should I solve it?

Comment: `confirm` or `alert` - depending on the browser implementation - block other parts from updates until the dialog is closed again (especially DOM update could be/are blocked) That does not mean that it is not executed before, but the update just arrives later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that JavaScript is single-threaded, and `confirm` is blocking.

`console.log`, as far as I can tell, is an asynchronous request for the console to log something. However, until the script has finished, it can't send that request. Same goes for `drawscreen`, the screen can't actually redraw until the script has finished.

Try wrapping your `if` block inside a `setTimeout(function() { ... },1);`, this will give the browser enough time to log the response and redraw the screen before getting right back to your `confirm`, without giving the user time to do anything that might interfere with normal operation.

Comment: +1 - now I understand the problem, thanks. Should I wrap the entire `if` statement or just its content? Should I put the `confirm` inside or outside the `setTimeout`?

Comment: The `confirm` needs to be inside the timeout, so wrap the entire `if` block.

Comment: wrapping the entire `if` didn't solved. However, wrapping just the `confirm()` part let the `drawScreen()` function start correctly (which is what I actually need). `console.log` still works right after the confirm, but who cares! I've solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: update - setTimeout wrapping the confirm and with an interval of 100ms solved also for console.log. Was trying with 10ms before...

Comment: Oh, I see, we weren't talking about the same `if` block XD

Comment: Damn! Now I understand! We definitely were talking about different `if`s! It really sounded strange to wrap the entire `if (response == "  ok")` block but I was totally sure you were referring to that! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Both **confirm** and **alert** are process blocking statements. They blocks the process in between and does not allow anything to reflect on **screen** until the Ok button is pressed.